# Keras gives Test Accuracy of 1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying with NFT image dataset with the following categories and distribution for prediction using CNN model.

```
    meebits                              60
    cool-cats-nft                        60
    fortune-friends-club-official-nft    32
    dava-humanoids                       31
    frenlypandas                         27
    mirlclub                             25
    psychopunks-nft                      19
    Name: Label, dtype: int64
    **********
    meebits                              0.236220
    cool-cats-nft                        0.236220
    fortune-friends-club-official-nft    0.125984
    dava-humanoids                       0.122047
    frenlypandas                         0.106299
    mirlclub                             0.098425
    psychopunks-nft                      0.074803
    Name: Label, dtype: float64
```

```
    CNN Model:
    model_2 = Sequential()
    
    # adding first conv layer with 256 filters and kernel size 5x5 , with ReLU activation 
    and padding 'same' provides the output size same as the input size
    #input_shape denotes input image dimension of images
    model_2.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (150,150,1)))  # Shape of the image given 
    to the model

    # adding max pooling to reduce the size of output of first conv layer
    model_2.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    #  adding dropout to randomly switch off 25% neurons to reduce overfitting
    model_2.add(Dropout(0.25))

    #  adding second conv layer with 128 filters and with kernel size 3x3 and ReLu 
    activation function
    model_2.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
    # adding max pooling havinf pool_size and strides with (2,2) to reduce the size of 
    output of second conv layer
    model_2.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
    #  adding dropout to randomly switch off 25% neurons to reduce overfitting
    model_2.add(Dropout(0.25))

    #  adding third conv layer with 128 filters and with kernel size 3x3 and ReLu activation 
    function
    model_2.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
    # adding max pooling havinf pool_size and strides with (2,2) to reduce the size of 
    output of third conv layer
    model_2.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
    #  adding dropout to randomly switch off 30% neurons to reduce overfitting
    model_2.add(Dropout(0.3))

    # adding fourth conv layer with 128 filters and with kernel size 2x2 and ReLu activation 
    function
    model_2.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (2,2),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
    # adding max pooling havinf pool_size and strides with (2,2) to reduce the size of 
    output of fourth conv layer
    model_2.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
    #  adding dropout to randomly switch off 30% neurons to reduce overfitting
    model_2.add(Dropout(0.3))

    #adding fifth conv layer with 128 filters and with kernel size 2x2 and ReLu activation 
    function
    model_2.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (2,2),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
    # adding max pooling havinf pool_size and strides with (2,2) to reduce the size of 
    output of fifth conv layer
    model_2.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
    #  adding dropout to randomly switch off 30% neurons to reduce overfitting
    model_2.add(Dropout(0.3))

    # flattening the 3-d output of the conv layer after max pooling to make it ready for 
    creating dense connections
    model_2.add(Flatten())
    # adding a fully connected dense layer with 1024 neurons 
    model_2.add(Dense(1024, activation = "relu"))
    #  adding dropout to randomly switch off 50% neurons to reduce overfitting
    model_2.add(Dropout(0.5))
    # adding the output layer with 4 neurons and activation functions as softmax since this 
    is a multi-class classification problem.
    model_2.add(Dense(7, activation = "softmax"))

    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
    # Compiling the model with Adam as optimizer, categorical_crossentropy as loss function 
    and accuracy as metrics
    model_2.compile(optimizer = optimizer , loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics= 
    ["accuracy"])
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=5)
    mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, 
    save_best_only=True)
    # Fitting the model with 30 epochs and validation_split as 20%
    history=model_2.fit(X_train, 
          y_train_e,  
          epochs=10, 
          batch_size=64,validation_split=0.20,callbacks=[es, mc])
```

```
 // for train-test split
    for i in classes:
     os.makedirs(rootdir +'/train/'+i)
     os.makedirs(rootdir +'/test/'+i)
     source = rootdir+'/'+i
     print(source)
     allFileNames = os.listdir(source)
     np.random.shuffle(allFileNames)
     test_ratio = 0.25
     train_FileNames, test_FileNames = 
     np.split(np.array(allFileNames),                                                   
     [int(len(allFileNames)* (1 - test_ratio))])
     train_FileNames = [source+'/'+ name for name in 
     train_FileNames.tolist()]
     test_FileNames = [source+'/' + name for name in 
     test_FileNames.tolist()]
     for name in train_FileNames:
       shutil.copy(name, rootdir +'/train/' + i)
     for name in test_FileNames:
       shutil.copy(name, rootdir +'/test/' + i)

    //for random image prediction
    img22 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(filepath),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array12 = cv2.resize(img22,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)) 
    plt.imshow(img22)
    plt.show()
    data1=[]
    X_train1 = []
    data1.append(new_array12)
    X_train1= np.array(data1) 
    res=model_2.predict(X_train1[0].reshape(1,150,150))
    plt.imshow(X_train1[0].reshape(150,150), cmap='Greys_r')
    i=np.argmax(res)
    print(i)
    print(y_test.Label[i]) **// is this the rigth way to retrieve 
    labels 
    accordingly**
```

The above model gives me the Test Accuracy of 1.0, I tried changing epoch and batch size , but the accuracy constantly is 1.0. I couldn't get whether is there any issue with dataset distribution ?

Comment: I would say your dataset is too small and is overfitting. Also, please mention your test-train (or, test-train-validation) split size. If didn't split the data before training, it is definitely overfitting.

Comment: Oh...I just manually move some data into a testing folder, I am completely new to this.. May I know if there any inbuilt APIs to split our data based on the distribution before training?

Comment: you can use the sklearn's train_test_split module to do this. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html try this.

Comment: I updated my question, with the code which I tried for the train-test split. Now Accuracy has been showing as 93%. But the Prediction was not showing correctly for all categories.. And I am not sure whether the label retrieval code which I did was correct?